# With eloquent to make search by 2 fields

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way in Laravel 5.6/MySQL 5.7 with eloquent to make search with condition:

> - need to check if sale_price is set then search in sale_price else in retail_price

Have I use condition like :

```
  \DB::raw( ‘ isNull( sale_price, retail_price ) > 10’ )
```

and how to modify the search above if both sale_price and retail_price are null?

Or there is better solution ?

MODIFIED :

I implemented it as scope :

```
public function scopeGetByDoublePrice($query, $price_from= null, $price_to= null)
{
    // need to check if sale_price is set then search in sale_price else in retail_price

    if ( empty($price_from) and empty($price_to) ) return $query;

    if ( !empty($price_from) ) { // $price_from is set
        $query->whereNotNull('sale_price')->where('sale_price', '>=', $price_from);
        $query->orWhere('retail_price', '>=', $price_from);
    } // if (!empty($price_from) ) { // $price_from is set


    if ( !empty($price_to) ) { // $price_to is set
        $query->whereNotNull('sale_price')->where('sale_price', '<=', $price_to);
        $query->orWhere('retail_price', '<=', $price_to);
    } // if (!empty($price_to) ) { // $price_to is set

    return $query;
}
```

but setting 2 values 31 and 33 I have different result I expected :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg78A.jpg
I expected only the first row would be in results set!

In sql-editor I set "()" manually, as :

SELECT  `sale_price`, `retail_price`
FROM `articles` 
LEFT JOIN brands     AS b  on b.id = articles.brand_id 
LEFT JOIN article_inventories     AS ai  on ai.article_id = articles.id 
WHERE ( ( `sale_price` is not null     AND `sale_price` >= '31'     OR `retail_price` >= '31'   )  AND 
   ( `sale_price` is not null     AND `sale_price` <= '33'     OR `retail_price` <= '33') )

and it works as I need. If there is a way to set "()" in my scope?

Comment: Why don't use `and` something like `->where('sale_price', 10, '>')->where('retail_price ', 10, '>')` this would work the same way.

Comment: Or something like `->where('sale_price', '>' ,10)->orWhere('retails_price' , '>' , 10)`

Answer (score 1):

Use to following constraint:

```
$price = 10;
$builder->where(function($query) use ($price) {
  $query->whereNotNull('sale_price')->where('sale_price', '>', $price);
  $query->orWhere('retail_price', '>', $price);
});
```

This will add the following to your query:

```
AND (sale_price IS NOT NULL and sale_price > 10 OR retail_price > 10)
```

What's important, you'll find those extra constraints wrapped in parenthesis which will let you avoid the situation, when other constraints are ignored because of the **OR**.

Comment: Thank you!
I modified original content, could you please take a look?

Comment: Just wrap scope constraints in a where() call like I did in my answer - this will get you the () you need